# How to split String with some separator but without removing that separator in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I'm facing problem in splitting `String`.

I want to split a `String` with some separator but without losing that separator.

When we use `somestring.split(String separator)` method in Java it splits the `String` but removes the separator part from `String`. I don't want this to  happen.

I want result like below:

```
String string1="Ram-sita-laxman";
String seperator="-";
string1.split(seperator);
```

Output:

```
[Ram, sita, laxman]
```

but I want the result like the one below instead:

```
[Ram, -sita, -laxman]
```

Is there a way to get output like this?

Answer (score 273):

```
string1.split("(?=-)");
```

This works because `split` actually takes a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). What you're actually seeing is a "zero-width positive lookahead".

I would love to explain more but my daughter wants to play tea party. :)

**Edit:** Back!

To explain this, I will first show you a different `split` operation:

```
"Ram-sita-laxman".split("");
```

This splits your string on every zero-length string. There is a zero-length string between every character. Therefore, the result is:

```
["", "R", "a", "m", "-", "s", "i", "t", "a", "-", "l", "a", "x", "m", "a", "n"]
```

Now, I modify my regular expression (`""`) to only match zero-length strings *if they are followed by a dash*.

```
"Ram-sita-laxman".split("(?=-)");
["Ram", "-sita", "-laxman"]
```

In that example, the `?=` means "lookahead". More specifically, it mean "*positive* lookahead". Why the "positive"? Because you can also have *negative* lookahead (`?!`) which will split on every zero-length string that is **not** followed by a dash:

```
"Ram-sita-laxman".split("(?!-)");
["", "R", "a", "m-", "s", "i", "t", "a-", "l", "a", "x", "m", "a", "n"]
```

You can also have *positive lookbehind* (`?<=`) which will split on every zero-length string that is preceded by a dash:

```
"Ram-sita-laxman".split("(?<=-)");
["Ram-", "sita-", "laxman"]
```

Finally, you can also have *negative lookbehind* (`?<!`) which will split on every zero-length string that is **not** preceded by a dash:

```
"Ram-sita-laxman".split("(?<!-)");
["", "R", "a", "m", "-s", "i", "t", "a", "-l", "a", "x", "m", "a", "n"]
```

These four expressions are collectively known as the *lookaround* expressions.

### Bonus: Putting them together

I just wanted to show an example I encountered recently that combines *two* of the lookaround expressions. Suppose you wish to split a CapitalCase identifier up into its tokens:

```
"MyAwesomeClass" => ["My", "Awesome", "Class"]
```

You can accomplish this using this regular expression:

```
"MyAwesomeClass".split("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])");
```

This splits on every zero-length string that is preceded by a lower case letter (`(?<=[a-z])`) and followed by an upper case letter (`(?=[A-Z])`).

This technique also works with camelCase identifiers.

Comment: Can you post an example of how you would do a lookaround that splits both before and after the hypens? 
ie. to produce `ram,-,sita,-,laxman`

Comment: How do I match to non-zero length strings? Like this "([non zero]?<=[a-z])([non zero]?=[A-Z])"?

Comment: @the_prole: Could you give some examples of what you mean?

Comment: Which browsers support this?
`"Ram-sita-laxman".split("(?<=-)");` results in one string `["Ram-sita-laxman"]`.

Comment: In hava this solution have a huge impact on performance, for example using negative lookbehind is 10 times slower then simply matching the "-" character

Comment: @wolfdawn this is for Java, Javascript distinguishes between strings and regex sequences, using forward slashes instead of quotes. `"Ram-sita-laxman".split(/(?<=-)/)` should work in Javascript

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit dodgy, but you could introduce a dummy separator using a replace function.  I don't know the Java methods, but in C# it could be something like:

```
string1.Replace("-", "#-").Split("#");
```

Of course, you'd need to pick a dummy separator that's guaranteed not to be anywhere else in the string.

Comment: dangerous (even if I have done it often :-)

Comment: Replace takes extra time, so this way is not optimal!

Answer (score 3):

Adam hit the nail on the head! I used his answer to figure out how to insert filename text from the file dialog browser into a rich text box. The problem I ran into was when I was adding a new line at the "\" in the file string. The string.split command was splitting at the \ and deleting it. After using a mixture of Adam's code I was able to create a new line after each \ in the file name.

Here is the code I used:

```
OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
        fd.Multiselect = true;
        fd.ShowDialog();

        foreach (string filename in fd.FileNames)
        {
            string currentfiles = uxFiles.Text;
            string value = "\r\n" + filename;

     //This line allows the Regex command to split after each \ in the filename. 

            string[] lines = Regex.Split(value, @"(?<=\\)");

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                uxFiles.Text = uxFiles.Text + line + "\r\n";
            }
        }
```

Enjoy!

Walrusking

Answer (score 2):

A way to do this is to split your string, then add your separator at the beginning of each extracted string except the first one.

Answer (score 1):

```
seperator="-";
String[] splitstrings = string1.split(seperator);
for(int i=1; i<splitstring.length;i++)
{
   splitstring[i] = seperator + splitstring[i];
}
```

that is the code fitting to LadaRaider's answer.