# Find out whether a file have extension or not

Tags: java

I have a file,sometimes with extension or with out extension. Using java how to find out whether a particular file having extension

Comment: Show us your effort. Voting to close as whatever.

Comment: do you know the file name?  if the name has a `.` in it followed by some letters, it has an extension

Comment: Letters or numbers.  For Blah.123, the extension is .123

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545937/java-splitting-the-filename-into-a-base-and-extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commons-io has a method that will get a file extension from a path or filename: [FilenameUtil.getExtension](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) for example

```
String result = FilenameUtils.getExtension( "foo.txt" );
```

Gives the result `txt`. If the file has no extension you will get the empty string back. A simple `isEmpty` check on the string will tell you if there is an extension. From the documentation:

> When dealing with filenames you can hit problems when moving from a Windows based development machine to a Unix based production machine. This class [Commons-io] aims to help avoid those problems.
>
> This method returns the textual part of the filename after the last dot. There must be no directory separator after the dot.

Comment: if you make this something other than a link-only answer, I'll undownvote

Comment: @SamIam: I would generally agree with you, but in this case there's not much more to say than that.

Comment: Thanks, for the up vote. It's a one line question that requires a one line answer. What more could I say?

Comment: @wobblycogs  well, if you don't want to add anything more(like an example or something) than that's your prerogative, but my downvote will remain if you don't

Comment: There, I edited the answer to improve it as suggested by the FAQ :-)

Comment: Fair enough, I could have added more of an answer initially.