# Improving file name readability in Java

Tags: java, file

I am working on a program that must print the names of each file and subfolder in a given directory.

So far I have the following (this is just the working code):

```
File directory = new File( [the path] );

File[] contents = directory.listFiles();

for ( File f : contents ) 
{
    String currentFile = f.getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println( currentFile ); 
}
```

This needs to be displayed to the user, who doesn't need to see the full path.  How can I get the output to only be the file names?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545937/java-splitting-the-filename-into-a-base-and-extension

Comment: Thank you so much for answering quickly, but what I want is something different - or your answer works but I'm not smart enough to implement it.

Comment: use getName() method from File class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file name is being printed as a simple `String`, meaning that it can be edited.  All you have to do is use `Str.replace` on your path.

This code `currentFile = currentFile.replace("`[the path]`", "");` would replace your file path with a blank, effectively erasing it.

Some code inserted correctly, such as

```
for ( File f : contents)
{
    currentFile = f.getAbsolutePath();
    currentFile = currentFile.replace("[the path]", "");
    System.out.println(currentFile);
}
```

will do this for each file your program finds.

Comment: why doing this, when File class already provide a method to obtain the file name?

Answer (score 1):

This should help you

```
File directory = new File("\\your_path");
File[] contents = directory.listFiles();
for (File f : contents) {
    System.out.println(f.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that sometimes ***you might not know the path*** base (for whatever reason), so there is a way to split the String. You just cut the part before the slash (`/`) and take all that's left. As you split it, there might be (and probably is) multiple slashes so you just take the last part

```
String currentFile;
String[] parts;
for ( File f : contents) {
    currentFile = f.getAbsolutePath();
    parts = currentFile.split("/");
    if (!parts.equals(currentFile)) {
        currentFile = parts[parts.length-1];
    }  
    System.out.println(currentFile);
}
```

**Example:** 
"file:///C:/Users/folder/Desktop/a.html" goes to be "a.html"

Comment: why doing this, when File class already provide a method to obtain the file name?

Comment: @JavaHopper You are right. Upvote to your answer. But well - at least mine works. :D

Comment: Partly to answer JavaHopper, this answer is the most modular - it could be repurposed to other, similar tasks.

Comment: That was the idea. I think OPs accepted answer is the.. last I would accept.