# How to split file name into base and extension

Tags: java, regex

So I'm trying to split a file name to the base and it's extension. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4546093/2859991) answer to this question, but I have another condition that this answer doesn't answer. I have a two conditions that I need to add:

**1.** If a file starts with "." and doesn't have any other period, then it counts like the first period is a part of the file's name, and there is no extension (the extension is "").
the answer in the link above

```
fileName.split("\\.(?=[^\\.]+$)")
```

will return for the given file name ".Myfile"

`["",MyFile"]`

but what I want it to return is

```
[.MyFile,""]
```

is there any way to do so using regex (changing the condition)?

**2.** I need 2 cells, no matter what the file name is. If the file name is "*README* " then I still want two cells to be created, the second one should contain an empty char.

I want:

> `[README,""]`

to be returned.

Is this possible?

***edit: solved!***
thanks to the help of *Wiktor Stribiżew* I solved it. I changed it to

```
String fileName;
String[] splitedName
String pat = "((?!^)\\.(?=[^.]*$|(?<=^\\.[^.]{0,1000})$))|$";
fileName = "README.txt"
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fileName .split(pat,2)));
fileName = ".README"
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fileName .split(pat,2)));
fileName = "README"
```

Result

```
"README.txt" => [REAADME,txt]
".README" => [REAADME, ]
"README" => [REAADME, ]
```

as I wanted.

Comment: At this point it feels like a short method to parse the filename is the better option.

Comment: Requirement stated in the above question is not exact match with the duplicate question

Comment: This is definatelly not a duplicate question. I even added the original qurstion and stated the 2 big difference that I need to make in order to get the correct form.

Comment: Check [this demo](http://ideone.com/lML25m)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final solution:

```
String pat = "(?!^)\\.(?=[^.]*$)|(?<=^\\.[^.]{0,1000})$|$";
```

The pattern consists of 3 alternatives to split with:

- `(?!^)\\.(?=[^.]*$)` - split with a dot that is not the first character in the string (`(?!^)`) and that has 0+ characters other than `.` to the right of it up to the string end (``)
- `(?<=^\\.[^.]{0,1000})$)` - split at the end of string if a string starts with a literal `.` and has 0 to 1000 characters (maybe setting to `1,256` is enough, but there are longer file names, please adjust accordingly)
- `$` - split at the end of string (replace with `\\z` if you need no `\n` if a string ends with `\n`)

When you pass `2` as a limit argument to the `split` method, you can limit the number of splits to just two, see [Java demo](http://ideone.com/92rldB):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(".MyFile".split(pat,2)));            // [.MyFile, ]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("MyFile.ext".split(pat,2)));         // [MyFile, ext]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("Another.MyFile.ext".split(pat,2))); // [Another.MyFile, ext]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("MyFile.".split(pat,2)));            // [MyFile, ]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("MyFile".split(pat,2)));             // [MyFile, ]
```

## Original answer

I believe you are looking for

```
(?!^)\\.(?=[^.]*$)|(?<=^\\.[^.]{0,1000})$
```

One note: the pattern that can be used with `split` uses a constrained-width lookbehind that assumes that the length of the file cannot be more than 1000. Increase the value as needed.

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/jkPfcq):

```
String pat = "(?!^)\\.(?=[^.]*$)|(?<=^\\.[^.]{0,1000})$";
String s = ".MyFile";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split(pat,-1)));
s = "MyFile.ext";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split(pat,-1)));
s = "Another.MyFile.ext";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split(pat,-1)));
s = "MyFile.";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split(pat,-1)));
```

Results:

```
".MyFile"            => [.MyFile, ]
"MyFile.ext"         => [MyFile, ext]
"Another.MyFile.ext" => [Another.MyFile, ext]
"MyFile."            => [MyFile, ]
```

Comment: first, Thank you!. you solved the first problem I had. but can you maybe help me with the second one as well? I want "_README_" outcome to be
'[README, ]' - if the original file name has no dot, I still want to consider it as an empty extension (" ")
and would it be possible if you explained the regex you wrote? thanks!

Comment: so I think I solved it, thanks to *Wiktor Stribiżew*/
I added |$ in the end, and in the split operation I limited it to 2 , meaning:
`String pat = "((?!^)\\.(?=[^.]*$|(?<=^\\.[^.]{0,1000})$))|$" 
'myText2.split(pat,2)`
and now I get the wanted result

Answer (score 0):

You could use a split to turn the file name into an array, and then loop through the array and find everything that is after the "."

Here is some example code.

```
    String str = "cat.txt";
    char[] cArray = str.toCharArray();
```

And then loop through the array and find the "." and capture everything after it.