# Splitting a string by a space without removing the space? 

Tags: c#, string, split

Something like: [How to split String with some separator but without removing that separator in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416425/how-to-split-string-with-some-seperator-but-without-removing-that-seperator-in-j)

I need to take "Hello World" and get ["Hello", " ", "World"]

Comment: Why? Why can't you just assume that there is a space between every two elements?

Comment: Why exactly? You know that the separator is a space, so for each element of the resulting array there would have been a space between the contiguous elements. If you use string.Join() you can put the space back in. I'm puzzled as to why you need it in the split results.

Comment: What would you want back if hello and world were seperated by more than one space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex, although it probably is an overkill :

```
StringCollection resultList = new StringCollection();
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(?:\b\w+\b|\s)");
Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResult.Success) {
    resultList.Add(matchResult.Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use [`Regex.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx) for this. If you enclose the pattern in capturing parentheses, it will be included in the result too:

```
Regex.Split("Hello World", "( )")
```

gives you exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you split on just the word-boundary, you'll get something very close to what you ask.

```
    string[] arr = Regex.Split("A quick brown fox.", "\\b");
```

arr[] = { "", "A", " ", "quick", " ", "brown", " ", "fox", "." }

Comment: Except that `string.Split()` doesn't work with regular expressions.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the reference to Java in the first line of the description and overlooked that there was a tag for C#.

Comment: I revised the example code to be written in C#.  The array results are the same.