# Split string in Java, retain delimiters including items inside quotes

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a .txt input file as follows:

```
Start "String" (100, 100) Test One:
  Nextline 10;
  Test Second Third(2, 4, 2, 4):
    String "7";
    String "8";
    Test "";
  End;
End.
```

I've intended to read this file in as one String and then split it based on certain delimiters.
I've almost met the desired output with this code:

```
String tr=  entireFile.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

String[] input = tr.split("(?<=[(,):;.])|(?=[(,):;.])|(?=\\p{Upper})");
```

My current output is:

```
Start"
String"
(
100
,
100
)
Test
One
:
Nextline10
;
Test
Second
Third
(
2
,
4
,
2
,
4
)
:
String"7"
;
String"8"
;
Test""
;
End
;
End
.
```

However, I'm having trouble treating items inside quotes or just plain quotes "" as a separate token. So "String" and "7" and "" should all be on separate lines. Is there a way to do this with regex? My expected output is below, thanks for any help.

```
Start
"String"
(
100
,
100
)
Test
One
:
Nextline
10
;
Test
Second
Third
(
2
,
4
,
2
,
4
)
:
String
"7"
;
String
"8"
;
Test
""
;
End
;
End
.
```

Comment: Where does "Hello" come from? Your input file starts with "Start". Please explain.

Comment: sorry, I changed it to make it more readable, edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the regex I came up with:

```
String[] input = entireFile.split(
        "\\s+|" +           // Splits on whitespace or 
        "(?<=\\()|" +         // splits on the positive lookbehind ( or
        "(?=[,).:;])|" +  // splits on any of the positive lookaheads ,).:; or
        "((?<!\\s)(?=\\())"); // splits on the positive lookahead ( with a negative lookbehind whitespace
```

To understand all that positive/negative lookahead/lookbehind terminology, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4416576).

Note that you should apply this split directly to the input file without removing whitespace, aka take out this line:

```
String tr=  entireFile.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

Comment: `[,\\)\\.:;]` can be simplified to `[,).:;]`

Comment: And `(\\s)+` can be simplified to `\\s+`, but well done

Comment: Thank you all for the input. The link was especially helpful in understanding lookarounds