# How to generate a regular expression that matches one specific string

Tags: python, regex

Here, I've tried to create a regular expression that matches one particular string:

```
#This is the string that the regex is intended to match
theString = "..!-+!)|(!+-!.."

print(re.compile(theString).match(theString))
```

This produces an error instead of matching the string:

```
raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

Is there any way to generate a regular expression that matches just one specific string, like this one?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  For example, the regex "apple" will only match the string "apple".

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression? You could just use a simple search function if it is really just a specific string.

Comment: @TimJones `re.compile("..!-+!)|(!+-!..")` does not match the string `"..!-+!)|(!+-!.."`.

Comment: The problem with that string is that it contains lots of characters that are "special" in regex syntax.

Comment: @zchrykng I'm using a regular expression because I need to generate a regex that I can use to [split another string without removing separators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416425/how-to-split-string-with-some-seperator-but-without-removing-that-seperator-in-j).

Comment: @AndersonGreen then pasztorpisti's answer is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping regex string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280435/escaping-regex-string-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import re
your_string = "..!-+!)|(!+-!.."
your_regex_string = "^" + re.escape(your_string) + "$"
your_regex = re.compile(your_regex_string)
```