# String Array Split Without Deleting

Tags: java, arrays, split

Hey guys i'm reading lines from .obj files and i want to load them into some arrays but i need to correctly parse them.

I'm reading some lines like this:
    f 19/19/115 25/25/116 17/22/117

And i want to split them by the "/" but without deleting that character, this is the result i want to obtain:

```
   [f,19,/,19,/,115,25,/,25,/,116,17,/,22,/,117]
```

And i'm when i do:

```
tokens = line.split("[/ ]+");
```

I'm getting:

```
[f, 19, 19, 115, 25, 25, 116, 17, 22, 117]
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29

Comment: If you try `string1.replace("/", "#/").split("#");` ? [same example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416425/how-to-split-string-with-some-separator-but-without-removing-that-separator-in-j)

Comment: You may find this answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters.

Comment: @Milaci this was my result:
[f 1, /1, /1 2, /2, /2 3, /3, /3]

Comment: @Milaci    [f,19,/,19,/,115,25,/,25,/,116,17,/,22,/,117]

Comment: This requirement is kind of odd. You want to split by a spacce and by a slash, but only the slash should be in the resulting array? I guess you need call the split* method two times. (* your implementation of it, that can keep the delimiter)

Comment: From that [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) _StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code._

Comment: already solved, official answer accepted

Comment: @Reimeus but it's not deprecated, works fine, and does the job that split() doesn't do.

Comment: @manouti How is the "arrays" tag related to this question? The result of `#split` is an array, yes, but this is just an unimportant information.

Comment: @Tom `split` returns an "array" of strings... And the OP wants to store results in an "array".

Comment: @manouti The array is not the question here. The question is "how to keep the delimiter". During a review you can reject edits like this perfectly with this text: `Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains.`. The array not is just uninteresting "side effect".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
tokens = line.split("(?<=/+)|(?=/+)| +");
```

`(?<=/+)`: match one or more / in lookbehind expression

`(?=/+)`: match one or more / in lookahead expression

Comment: [f 1, /1, /1 2, /2, /2 3, /3, /3]
I got this also

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("f 19/19/115 25/25/116 17/22/117".replace("/","#/#").split("[# ]")));
```