# Java- Split String which is alphanumeric

Tags: java, string, split

Example input:

```
RC23
CC23QQ21HD32
BPOASDf91A5HH123
```

Example output:

```
[RC,23]
[CC,23,QQ,21,HD,32]
[BPOASDf,91,A,5,HH,123]
```

The length of alpha part and numeric part is not fixed.

I know how to use split() with regex like `//.' ' ' '([a-z])` but although I checked `split()` Java API I can't find anything that can help me to solve this problem.

Is there a way to use `split()` to do this? Or I need to use another method to split these string.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried a loop?

Comment: Check this out: [Simplify splitting a String into alpha and numeric parts](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2345/simplify-splitting-a-string-into-alpha-and-numeric-parts). The solution to the problem is the following regex: `"[^A-Z0-9]+|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])"`

Comment: I tried to use a loop, but for my application it will run in O(n^2). So loop is not a good choice for me. I'm considering split them into parts and process the string array. It saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this regex: `"((?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9]))|((?<=[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z]))"`

Here's a running example: http://ideone.com/c02rmM

```
{
    ...
    String someString = "CC23QQ21HD32";
    String regex = "((?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9]))|((?<=[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z]))";
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(someString.split(regex)));
    //outputs [CC, 23, QQ, 21, HD, 32]
    ...
}
```

The regex is using *lookahead* `(?=ValueToMatch)` and *look behinds* `(?<=ValueToMatch)`.

The first half of it (before the | ) is asking: "Is the previous character a letter `(?<=[a-zA-Z])`? Is the next character a digit `(?=[0-9])`?" If both are true, it'll match the string to the regex.

The second half of that regex is doing it the other way around. It asks: "Is the previous character a digit `(?<=[0-9])`? Is the next character a letter? `(?=[a-zA-Z])`", and again it'll match if both are true.

Normally the split() would remove the characters matched by the regex. This remains true even to this regex. However, since the regex is matching a 0-width lookahead, the actual characters you're looking for are not removed.

Check out Adam Paynter's answer for more on *lookaheads* and *look behinds*: [how to split string with some separator but without removing that separator in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416425/how-to-split-string-with-some-separator-but-without-removing-that-separator-in-j)

Comment: Good answer. Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can match on 1 or more contiguous alpha characters or 1 or more contiguous numerical characters. Once the sequence is interrupted stop matching, store the sequence an then start over. Non-word characters will be ignored entirely.

**Edit:** I created a simple performance test below to show the speed between using `String.split()` and `Pattern.matcher()`. The split version is 2.5x faster than the matcher+loop version.

#### Solution

```
private static String[] splitAlphaNumeric(String str) {
    return str.split("(?i)((?<=[A-Z])(?=\\d))|((?<=\\d)(?=[A-Z]))");
}
```

#### Example

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class SplitAlphaNumeric {
    private static final Pattern ALPH_NUM_PAT = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+|[A-Z]+");

    private static List<String> input = Arrays.asList(
        "RC23",
        "CC23QQ21HD32",
        "BPOASDf91A5HH123"
    );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("Execution time: %dns%n", testMatch());
        System.out.printf("Execution time: %dns%n", testSplit());
    }

    public static long testMatch() {
        System.out.println("Begin Test 1...");
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (String str : input) {
            System.out.printf("%-16s -> %s%n", str, parse(str));
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        return end - start;
    }

    public static long testSplit() {
        System.out.println("\nBegin Test 2...");
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (String str : input) {
            System.out.printf("%-16s -> %s%n", str, parse2(str));
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        return end - start;
    }

    private static List<String> parse(String str) {
        List<String> parts = new LinkedList<String>();
        Matcher matcher = ALPH_NUM_PAT.matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            parts.add(matcher.group());
        }
        return parts;
    }

    private static List<String> parse2(String str) {
        return Arrays.asList(str.split("(?i)((?<=[A-Z])(?=\\d))|((?<=\\d)(?=[A-Z]))"));
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Begin Test 1...
RC23             -> [RC, 23]
CC23QQ21HD32     -> [CC, 23, QQ, 21, HD, 32]
BPOASDf91A5HH123 -> [BPOASD, 91, A, 5, HH, 123]
Execution time: 4879125ns

Begin Test 2...
RC23             -> [RC, 23]
CC23QQ21HD32     -> [CC, 23, QQ, 21, HD, 32]
BPOASDf91A5HH123 -> [BPOASDf, 91, A, 5, HH, 123]
Execution time: 1953349ns
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookahead, something like "`((?<=%1[0-9]+)|(?=%1[0-9]+))`"