# Replace a camelCase01 by camel_case_01

Tags: java, regex, string, format

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String key = "camelCase01";
    System.out.println(caseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL.to(caseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE, key));
    }
}
```

Output : camel_case01

But I want to print line camel_case_01

Comment: Replace `(?=\d+)` with `_`.

Comment: this will print camel_case_0_1.@AndyTurner But I need to be print camel_case_01

Comment: You want regex only to do this job? Since this can be easily done in other ways in java.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do this.

Split the string into alpha and numeric values i.e. separate the numbers from the alphabets. See here - [Java- Split String which is alphanumeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595868/java-split-string-which-is-alphanumeric)

Then, apply the snake_casing on all strings of alphabets and join the array with an "_"

Answer (score 0):

As Java does not seem to support case conversion using `\l`, you can try this method:

```
public static String toSnake(String s) {
        return s.replaceAll("([A-Z]|\\d+)", "_$1") // add _ before a cap letter or sequence of digits
                .replaceAll("_+", "_") // replace multiple underscores with one
                .replaceAll("^_", "")  // remove leading underscores
                .toLowerCase();
}

// Test
Arrays.asList(
    "camelCase01", "anotherCamelCase", "version1", 
    "version1_2", "PascalCase", "123SlySnake")
    .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + " -> " + toSnake(s)));
```

*Output*

```
camelCase01 -> camel_case_01
anotherCamelCase -> another_camel_case
version1 -> version_1
version1_2 -> version_1_2
PascalCase -> pascal_case
123SlySnake -> 123_sly_snake
```