# Java split by dash character

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm trying to split a string by a hyphen and a character but unsure of how to use split with Regex. The string is this:

–u tom –p 12345 –h google.com

The hyphen and character are interchangeable in position and how many of them may appear. I'd like them back in an array. Here is what I have so far:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
String entireLine = reader.nextLine();
String[] array = entireLine.split("–", -1);
```

The result I'd like is:

–u tom

–p 12345

–h google.com

Thanks.

Comment: this is not the best way to parse command line parameters; look into some library like jargs

Comment: I just wanted some a quick thing, HW related. Not concerned with polishing it. Just getting the result.

Comment: what if user input has hyphens: -u peter-p -p pass-word -h my-domain.com    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java

Comment: It won't, we know that ahead of time.

Comment: @NikitaIgnatov You would need to incorporate the `space` character in addition to the `dash` character (or `hyphen`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to split string with some separator but without removing that separator in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416425/how-to-split-string-with-some-separator-but-without-removing-that-separator-in-j)

Comment: This question is more regarding the Reggix and less about the Java Split method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] array = entireLine.split("(?<!^)(?=-)");
```

The negative look behind will prevent splitting at the start of line.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for to ignore the first one. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following:

```
String[] array = entireLine.split("\\-", -1);
// or
String[] array = entireLine.split("\\–", -1);
```

It would give you

u tom

p 12345

h google.com

Comment: @AzzamAziz How about a +1 for solving your problem ?

Comment: @mrres1 I actually just got the ability of +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

The `split` method takes a regular expression in its parameter, so you can use *positive lookahead* like this

```
String[] array = entireLine.split("(?=-)");
```

You have a great explanation of this in a similar question to yours: [How to split String with some separator but without removing that separator in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416425/how-to-split-string-with-some-separator-but-without-removing-that-separator-in-j)

Comment: @AzzamAziz Why not? I have tried the input `-a b -c d` and it returns `-a b` and `-c d`. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: This worked after I changed my - character. I was using the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
String[] array = entireLine.split("-*(\\s+)");
```