# Java split String by token

Tags: java, regex, string

The code below:

```
String str = "She is a girl";
String[] substr = str.split("is");
```

The output for substr[1] is "a girl". But my expected is the output "is a girl". How can I solve this? Can I split the string based on the index of token?

Answer (score 4):

Use a positive lookahead token.

```
String[] substr = str.split("(?=is)");
```

Answer (score 3):

`str.substring(str.indexOf("is"))`

If you want to get the first part of the string, you may call `str.substring(0, str.indexOf("is"))`

Edit: check out the answer by @Codebender 
It's more apt for this question.

Comment: OP wants to get second part with delimiter. However your answer covers only first part which is irrelevant for OP

Comment: @Panther `string.substring(x)` is equal to `string.substring(x, string.length())`

Comment: Sorry i missed the first part of answer. I started reading from text and saw only second part. My bad :-(

Answer (score 0):

As split method excludes the token, the output of you program is correct. For your need instead of `split` , you can use `substring` and `index` as below

```
String str = "She is a girl";
String substr1 = str.substring(str.indexOf("is"), str.length);
```

Prefer substring if you need to get one part of string. Split is good when you need to break string into multiple strings based on token.

If you want to use split only or have multiple tokens and want to include token also, you can use [look ahead token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416425/how-to-split-string-with-some-separator-but-without-removing-that-separator-in-j)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `replaceFirst`

```
string.replaceFirst(".*?\\b(is)\\b", $1);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dO0mM8/1)