# regex how to split String without removing that seperator and adding it in seperate way

Tags: java, regex

regarding this topic: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416425/how-to-split-string-with-some-separator-but-without-removing-that-separator-in-j#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416425/how-to-split-string-with-some-separator-but-without-removing-that-separator-in-j#_=_)

I want to know how to make from this string:

```
String string1="Ram-sita-laxman";
```

seperation like this:

```
["Ram", "-" , "sita", "-",  "laxman"]
```

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use look ahead and look behind like following

```
    String string1="Ram-sita-laxman";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(string1.split("((?<=-)|(?=-))")));
```

In this the output will be
`[Ram, -, sita, -, laxman]`

Notice that while the delimiter is there but not everything is in quotes cause it can't be unless you add them yourself in the array

Hope this helps.

Comment: If i make  `string1.split("((?<=and|or)|(?=and|or))");`
i get split by words "**and**" and "**or**" i want additionaily split by brackets "**(**" and "**)**" how can i make it?
Thank you for your response :)

Comment: @yami You already have the elements in an array in the answer I had givem. You can just loop the array and add the double quotes to each element

Comment: Sir, i asked kind of a different question now.
not about quotes `" "` But how to split string in 1 operation by 4 strings: **"and"** **"or"**     **"("**        **")"**
Let's say starting string was: `(a=1 and b=2) or(a=3 and b=4)`