# Splitting string in between two characters in Java

Tags: java, regex, split

I am currently attempting to interpret some code I wrote for something. The information I would like to split looks something like this:

`{hey=yes}TEST`

What I am trying to accomplish, is splitting above string in between '}' and 'T' (T, which could be any letter). The result I am after is (in pseudocode):

`["{hey=yes}", "TEST"]`

How would one go about doing so? I know basic regex, but have never gotten into using it to split strings in between letters before.

**Update:**

In order to split the string I am using the String.split method. Do tell if there is a better way to go about doing this.

Comment: with which logic you are spiting the string is needed... if possible provide that too....

Comment: If by logic you mean what sort of method I use, the description of the problem has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use String's split method, as follow:

```
String str = "{hey=foo}TEST";
String[] split = str.split("(?<=})");       
System.out.println(split[0] + ", " + split[1]);
```

It splits the string and prints this:

> {hey=foo}, TEST

- `?<=}`, is to split after the character `}` and **keep the character** while doing it. By default, if you just split on a character, it will be removed by the split.
- This other answer provides a complete explanation of all options when using the split method:
  [how-to-split-string-with-some-separator-but-without-removing-that-separator-in-j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416425/how-to-split-string-with-some-separator-but-without-removing-that-separator-in-j)

Answer (score 2):

Usage of regexp for such a small piece of code can be really slow, if it is repeated thousands of times (e.g. like analysing Alfresco metadata for lot of documents).

Look at this snippet:

```
    String s = "{key=value}SOMETEXT";
    String[] e = null;
    long now = 0L;

    now = new Date().getTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3000000; i++) {
        e = s.split("(?<=})");
    }
    System.out.println("Regexp: " + (new Date().getTime() - now));

    now = new Date().getTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3000000; i++) {
        int idx = s.indexOf('}') + 1;
        e = new String[] { s.substring(0, idx), s.substring(idx) };
    }
    System.out.println("IndexOf:" + (new Date().getTime() - now));
```

result is

```
Regexp: 2544
IndexOf:113
```

This means that regexp is 25 times slower than a (easier) substring. Keep it in mind: it can make the difference between a efficient code and a elegant (!) one.

Comment: If the use case is processing several millions of records, there _might_ be point in optimizing the code. Otherwise focus on reliable and readable code. Remember Michael A Jacksons quote: “Rules of Optimization:
Rule 1: Don't do it.
Rule 2 (for experts only): Don't do it yet.”

Answer (score -2):

If you're looking for a regex approach and also want some *validation that  input follows the expected syntax* you probably want something like this:

```
public List<String> splitWithRegexp(String string)
{
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\{.*\\})(.*)").matcher(string);
    if (matcher.find()) 
        return Arrays.asList(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input didn't match!");
}
```

The parenthesis in the regexp captures groups, which you can access with `matcher.group(n)` calls. Group `0` matches the whole pattern.

Comment: And if you worry about performance, declare the `Pattern.compile("(\\{.*\\})(.*)")` as a `static final` field and use that field in your method.