# Spliting the word in to 2 words in Java

Tags: java

How to split a word to 2 words example like

```
 String a="pavanpavan"
```

and to print this in 2 variables like

```
a1="pavan"
a2="pavan"
```

I've tried to split using the `split("p")`, but the output will be

```
avan
avan
```

How to print full word as pavan and pavan?

Comment: How about taking first half substring and second half of the substring ?

Comment: What is the actual rule you want to split on?  Are you actually just looking for the literal string "pavenpaven", or is there a more general rule of which this is an example?

Answer (score 2):

A workaround for simply doing this would be.

```
a1 = a.substring(0,a.length()/2);

a2 = a.substring(a.length()/2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways: first one is to use `.substring()`

```
String a ="pavanpavan";
String a1 = a.substring(0, 5);
String a2 = a.substring(5);
```

And the second using `.split()` and regex

```
String a="pavanpavan";
String[] array = a.split("(?=p)");
String a1 = array[0];
String a2 = array[1];
```

Source: [How to split String with some separator but without removing that separator in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416425/how-to-split-string-with-some-separator-but-without-removing-that-separator-in-j)

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = a.lastIndexOf("pavan");
if (i != -1) {
    String b = a.substring(i); //pavan
    String c = a.substring(0, i); //pavan
}
```