# Split text contains number to list of string

Tags: java

I have numbers and to want to split it to list of string using special character on it and with out removing special character on it like split

```
1,245.00
to
1
,
245
.
00
```

Comment: Hint: [`Character.isDigit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit-char-)

Comment: [`str.split("\\b")`](https://ideone.com/09yDNv)

Comment: @4castle Nice answer, but perhaps if the OP would want to split at certain types of non word boundary characters then this might not work as planned.

Comment: Refer this question,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416425/how-to-split-string-with-some-separator-but-without-removing-that-separator-in-j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your string using lookaheads:

```
String input = "1,245.00";
String[] parts = input.split("(?=[^A-Za-z0-9])|(?<=[^A-Za-z0-9])");
for(String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

This splits if, at any position is the string, either the preceding or proceeding character be a non letter or number.

**Output:**

```
1
,
245
.
00
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options available. You can use the boundary (credits to @4castle), but also lookahead (credits to the [previous reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46538549/2735286)) and lookbehind.

Here are three options which all work:

```
String input = "1,245.00";
// look-ahead only
Stream.of(input.split("(?=[,.])|(?<=[^\\d])")).forEach(System.out::println);
System.out.println();
// Boundary
Stream.of(input.split("\\b")).forEach(System.out::println);
System.out.println();
// Mix of look-behind and look-ahead
Stream.of(input.split("(?![\\d])|(?<=[^\\d])")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

All print together:

```
1
,
245
.
00

1
,
245
.
00

1
,
245
.
00
```